# How I can verify credentials for domain name with Credentials-plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to verify and validate credentials (user and password) by using Credentials-plugin for Jenkins. I added Credentials-plugin in my POM file. But I don't know how to verify access to my domain name.

Do you have any idea how I can verify credentials for a domain name (aa.example.com) by using credentials-plugin through java.
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about Jenkins' [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)? Why and how did you add this to a Maven project's POM? This is a plugin for Jenkins, not for Maven.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about Jenkins, I'm working in other plugin that I want to use credential plugin to verify access to domain name. for maven I mean, add dependency in maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins 'credential' plugin is to facilitate keeping passwords(user/pwd or any other form) safe outside of code. So you can only use those wherever you want in code by using the variable names you have created in configuration. Jenkins will get this password to you wherever you ask but it will not use those for any authentication. It is up to us to get the values through system vairables and use them to authenticate for given domain name. Refer below to see if that is helping you.

[Inject passwords to the build as environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764521/inject-passwords-to-the-build-as-environment-variables)